# Why Skealearn-NearestNeighbors returns a werid/wrong results?

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

- Code

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1])
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4, algorithm='kd_tree').fit(X)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(X)

print(indices)
print(distances)
print(nbrs.kneighbors_graph(X).toarray())
```

- Results

```
[[0 1 2 3]
 [1 0 2 3]
 [2 1 0 3]
 [3 4 5 0]
 [4 3 5 0]
 [5 4 3 0]]
[[0.         1.         2.23606798 2.82842712]
 [0.         1.         1.41421356 3.60555128]
 [0.         1.41421356 2.23606798 5.        ]
 [0.         1.         2.23606798 2.82842712]
 [0.         1.         1.41421356 3.60555128]
 [0.         1.41421356 2.23606798 5.        ]]
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

For the last three points, I think the 4th data is the closest.
Why the code returns the first data as the closest?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know exactly what you mean by the last three points being closest to the 4th data. But if you compare the `distances` to the `indices`, the output seems right to me.

Comment: Hi Jim, Get it. Just confused by the output of `nbrs.kneighbors_graph(X).toarray()`. The original data X were not arranged from left to right. Thanks for your timely reply : )